# Excel passwords

Tags: excel, vba, passwords

I have a bit of experience with VBA but I am not an expert by any means. I have never really bothered much with passwords and such. I have never really been in a situation where felt a need to protect my code. Also I understand there are different passwords for different items (I have already googled this). Anyways, I have an excel document. It has a password to open it. I have this password, so no problem there. It has a password on the VBA code. I found this code to bypass this password (and it works just fine):

```
Private Const PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = &H40

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub MoveMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
    (Destination As LongPtr, Source As LongPtr, ByVal Length As LongPtr)

Private Declare PtrSafe Function VirtualProtect Lib "kernel32" (lpAddress As LongPtr, _
    ByVal dwSize As LongPtr, ByVal flNewProtect As LongPtr, lpflOldProtect As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetModuleHandleA Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lpModuleName As String) As 
LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpProcName As String) As LongPtr

Private Declare PtrSafe Function DialogBoxParam Lib "user32" Alias "DialogBoxParamA" (ByVal hInstance As LongPtr, _
    ByVal pTemplateName As LongPtr, ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpDialogFunc As LongPtr, ByVal dwInitParam As LongPtr) As Integer

Dim HookBytes(0 To 11) As Byte
Dim OriginBytes(0 To 11) As Byte
Dim pFunc As LongPtr
Dim Flag As Boolean

Private Function GetPtr(ByVal Value As LongPtr) As LongPtr
GetPtr = Value
End Function

Public Sub RecoverBytes()
If Flag Then MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), 12
End Sub

Public Function Hook() As Boolean

Dim TmpBytes(0 To 11) As Byte
Dim p As LongPtr, osi As Byte
Dim OriginProtect As LongPtr

Hook = False

#If Win64 Then
    osi = 1
#Else
    osi = 0
#End If

pFunc = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("user32.dll"), "DialogBoxParamA")

If VirtualProtect(ByVal pFunc, 12, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, OriginProtect) <> 0 Then

    MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(TmpBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, osi+1
    If TmpBytes(osi) <> &HB8 Then

        MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(OriginBytes(0)), ByVal pFunc, 12

        p = GetPtr(AddressOf MyDialogBoxParam)

        If osi Then HookBytes(0) = &H48
        HookBytes(osi) = &HB8
        osi = osi + 1
        MoveMemory ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(osi)), ByVal VarPtr(p), 4 * osi
        HookBytes(osi + 4 * osi) = &HFF
        HookBytes(osi + 4 * osi + 1) = &HE0

        MoveMemory ByVal pFunc, ByVal VarPtr(HookBytes(0)), 12
        Flag = True
        Hook = True
    End If
End If

End Function

Private Function MyDialogBoxParam(ByVal hInstance As LongPtr, _
    ByVal pTemplateName As LongPtr, ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpDialogFunc As LongPtr, ByVal dwInitParam As LongPtr) As Integer

If pTemplateName = 4070 Then
    MyDialogBoxParam = 1
Else
    RecoverBytes
    MyDialogBoxParam = DialogBoxParam(hInstance, pTemplateName, _
        hWndParent, lpDialogFunc, dwInitParam)
    Hook
End If

End Function


''''RUN THE CODE BELOW''''
Sub VBAUnprotected()

If Hook Then
    MsgBox "VBA Project is unprotected!", vbInformation, "*****"
End If

End Sub
```

I am running excel 2013 by the way but i don't know what version this document was originally saved with.

Anyways, like I said, the code above seems to work like a charm but the VBA code references and excel sheet that I don't see. My assumption is that the sheet has been hidden. I need to see this sheet because of some calculations on this sheet. However, I cannot "unhide" this sheet because the sheet is password protected. So I tried this code:

```
Sub BreakPassword()

   Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer 
   Dim l As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer
   Dim i1 As Integer, i2 As Integer, i3 As Integer
   Dim i4 As Integer, i5 As Integer, i6 As Integer

   On Error Resume Next

   For i = 65 To 66: For j = 65 To 66: For k = 65 To 66
   For l = 65 To 66: For m = 65 To 66: For i1 = 65 To 66
   For i2 = 65 To 66: For i3 = 65 To 66: For i4 = 65 To 66
   For i5 = 65 To 66: For i6 = 65 To 66: For n = 32 To 126

   ActiveSheet.Unprotect Chr(i) & Chr(j) & Chr(k) & _
   Chr(l) & Chr(m) & Chr(i1) & Chr(i2) & Chr(i3) & _
   Chr(i4) & Chr(i5) & Chr(i6) & Chr(n)

   If ActiveSheet.ProtectContents = False Then
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next
   Next: Next: Next: Next: Next: Next

End Sub
```

This just ran and ran and ran for I am not sure how long but maybe and hour? or at least 30 minutes? Should it take that long? I finally manually aborted... I kinda understand this code... it is trying every combination of letters and numbers until it passes the password. However, my question is this... The origin of the document is Japan... I can read the "code" but the comments are random symbols "not Japanese" Maybe I need to install something in excel so that excel can read the Japanese but usually what actually happens is the Japanese gets turned into random symbols during zip and unzip. So my question is this:

Will the password breaker above work if the password is Japanese? my guess is not... My understanding is that the code above tries all numbers and letters of the English alphabet, whereas the Japanese alphabet is thousands of letters. Will this code run in an infinite loop if the password is not in English? Lastly, is there a way to see what the password actually is? not just bypass it? Bypassing would be fine but finding out the actual password would be neat. Here is an actual piece of the  code i was able to unlock, unfortunately I can not (should not show much).

```
On Error GoTo ErrMsg1 '‰½‚ç‚©‚ÌƒGƒ‰[‚ª”­¶‚µ‚½ê‡‚ÍAƒGƒ‰[ƒƒbƒZ[ƒW‚ð•\Ž¦‚·‚éB

'“ü—Íƒf[ƒ^‚Ìƒ`ƒFƒbƒN‚±‚±‚©‚ç
If Worksheets("calc").Range("H2").Value = 0 Then
```

My guess is that this:

```
'“ü—Íƒf[ƒ^‚Ìƒ`ƒFƒbƒN‚±‚±‚©‚ç
```

is actually a comment written in Japanese characters but zipping and unzipping has returned non-sense. This is ok because i can understand the VBA code without the comments.

Comment: Please note that SO cannot help in illegal actions like cracking passwords. Note that the password breaker will not find the original password but an alternative one that works to get in. This is possible due to a bad design of Microsoft.

Comment: I love your use of Windows DLLs btw. In the years before PowerShell, Win32 and VBA was how I moved mountains. Then PS came along and everyone thought it was wonderful and I was just wondering what the heck they were doing for 10 years - because I had no need for Powershell.

Comment: Understood... This is not illegal activity... Anyways, there is plenty of info on SO for how to unlock this document. However, I have not run into any examples pertaining to Japanese documents and most of my questions are to satisfy my curiosities, not because I am stuck.

Comment: Sorry I can't take credit for the first code... I hardly understand it... I found it on SO and it worked.

Comment: This algorithm does not care about if it is chinese or japanese. It just finds any password that creates a collition with the hash of the original password. There is not only one password to get in but any password that has the same hash.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  are you referring to the first code? I understand it is messing with the memory (hash?). I have no trouble with this code... It is the second code that I am having trouble with. The second code isn't dealing with hash is it? and if it is... How long might I expect that I should let this code run? minutes? Hours? days?

Comment: @XCELLGUY I answered it below, comments were too short. Passwords are always dealing with a hash. Note that the second algorithm only works for old files. Newer ones have a better hash.

Answer (score 1):

To unhide all worksheets eg in `workbook to unhide.xlsm` open it. Then open a new workbook and add the following code in the new workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UnhideAllWorkbooks()
    With Workbooks("workbook to unhide.xlsm") 'this is not this workbook
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            .Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

After that all hidden sheets should be vibisble.

---

Explanation to some of the quesitons:

> Will this code run in an infinite loop if the password is not in English?

No, the `BreakPassword` algorithm will just create a new password that has the same hash as the original one. Since both passwords match the same hash and Excel just compares the hashes in the end, you can get in with both.

> Lastly, is there a way to see what the password actually is? not just bypass it?

No, there is only the hash in the file and a hash is *"one way"* direction. It is like if you have `1 + 2 + 3 + 4` and the hash is the sum = `10`. If you only know the hash is 10 you cannot tell which numbers `a + b + c + d` were used to sum up to `10`. You can find a solution but (likely) not the solution that was originally used.

Actually the `BreakPassword` algorithm only works for older Excel files where Microsoft used a very poor hashing algorithm. No matter how long or complicated the original password was it is possible to create a collition with this hash with just 6 characters (which can be brute forced in a quite short amount of time).
Newer Excel files use a better hash algorithm. Therefore it does not work there anymore.

Comment: "Microsoft used a very poor hashing algorithm" - an understatement there :-)

Comment: @BigBen Yes, actually it was hard for me to find words for how bad it really is, sorry ;)

Comment: So firstly... I ran your code and got an error... I assume this is because you have "end if" not "end sub." No problem, I changed to end sub... To my surprise excel closed and reopened and the hidden tab was still hidden. Why? Firstly... Your code isn't even attempting to crack the worksheet password... You are simply saying "unhide them"... do i need to run some other code before running your code? and why would the workbook close and reopen after running your code...

Comment: also i just saw the comment about old files... how can i tell if this is an old file? or a new file?

Comment: @XCELLGUY yes my fault it should `End Sub` obviously. Actually I have no idea why the workbook reopens (the code does not do this). And yes you don't need to crack any worksheet passwords because a protected sheet does not protect it from unhiding (it just protects from editing). Try it with a new workbook. Protect a sheet and hide it. The code can unhide it. The password is not needed to unhide it.

Comment: I don't think that is true because... If that was true... I should be able to right click on a tab... select all tabs (sheets)... and go to format... and then unhide... but when I try this... format is grayed out. Also, I just tried the password breaker again... This time i added a counter to display "Debug.Print count" to the immediate window... it looped through 64 iterations the first time... tried again... it looped through a little over 7 thousand... both only took seconds, then excel locks up. I have to ctrl alt delete... this must be similar to what happened yesterday when I first tried

Comment: Based on what I am reading, there are only 65,000 cache combinations or so... So it should unlock in a minute or 2 if it is getting to 7 thousands in 5 seconds

Comment: Maybe the immediate window isn't updating as fast?

Comment: lol... it stops at 32,767... because i made the count an integer... thats the limit for an integer... I guess I knew there was a limit but have never made a counter that would count that high

Comment: I changed to long data type and it stops at 194,560... It shouldn't even be going through that many iterations right? And when its done it is still password protected....

Comment: @XCELLGUY The first 11 loops run from `65 To 66` makes `2` each so `2^11 = 2048` and the last one runs from `32 To 126` makes `95` so `2048 × 95 = 194560`. That means if you reach that number the code run through without finding any hash collision. Means it could not break the password protection, so it is the new file with the better hash, that cannot be cracked with this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... The only way i was able to solve my problem was this... I first saved my file as .xlsx type... this lost the VBA but that's ok as i said earlier... I have already been able to access the vba. So i will have to manually add it back in. Then I used this code:

```
Sub RemoveProtection()

Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Dim sourceFullName As String
Dim sourceFilePath As String
Dim sourceFileName As String
Dim sourceFileType As String
Dim newFileName As Variant
Dim tempFileName As String
Dim zipFilePath As Variant
Dim oApp As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim xmlSheetFile As String
Dim xmlFile As Integer
Dim xmlFileContent As String
Dim xmlStartProtectionCode As Double
Dim xmlEndProtectionCode As Double
Dim xmlProtectionString As String

'Open dialog box to select a file
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False
dialogBox.Title = "Select file to remove protection from"

If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
    sourceFullName = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

'Get folder path, file type and file name from the sourceFullName
sourceFilePath = Left(sourceFullName, InStrRev(sourceFullName, "\"))
sourceFileType = Mid(sourceFullName, InStrRev(sourceFullName, ".") + 1)
sourceFileName = Mid(sourceFullName, Len(sourceFilePath) + 1)
sourceFileName = Left(sourceFileName, InStrRev(sourceFileName, ".") - 1)

'Use the date and time to create a unique file name
tempFileName = "Temp" & Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

'Copy and rename original file to a zip file with a unique name
newFileName = sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip"
On Error Resume Next
FileCopy sourceFullName, newFileName

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to copy " & sourceFullName & vbNewLine _
        & "Check the file is closed and try again"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Create folder to unzip to
zipFilePath = sourceFilePath & tempFileName & "\"
MkDir zipFilePath

'Extract the files into the newly created folder
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oApp.Namespace(zipFilePath).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(newFileName).items

'loop through each file in the \xl\worksheets folder of the unzipped file
xmlSheetFile = Dir(zipFilePath & "\xl\worksheets\*.xml*")
Do While xmlSheetFile <> ""

    'Read text of the file to a variable
    xmlFile = FreeFile
    Open zipFilePath & "xl\worksheets\" & xmlSheetFile For Input As xmlFile
    xmlFileContent = Input(LOF(xmlFile), xmlFile)
    Close xmlFile

    'Manipulate the text in the file
    xmlStartProtectionCode = 0
    xmlStartProtectionCode = InStr(1, xmlFileContent, "<sheetProtection")

    If xmlStartProtectionCode > 0 Then

        xmlEndProtectionCode = InStr(xmlStartProtectionCode, _
            xmlFileContent, "/>") + 2 '"/>" is 2 characters long
        xmlProtectionString = Mid(xmlFileContent, xmlStartProtectionCode, _
            xmlEndProtectionCode - xmlStartProtectionCode)
        xmlFileContent = Replace(xmlFileContent, xmlProtectionString, "")

    End If

    'Output the text of the variable to the file
    xmlFile = FreeFile
    Open zipFilePath & "xl\worksheets\" & xmlSheetFile For Output As xmlFile
    Print #xmlFile, xmlFileContent
    Close xmlFile

    'Loop to next xmlFile in directory
    xmlSheetFile = Dir

Loop

'Read text of the xl\workbook.xml file to a variable
xmlFile = FreeFile
Open zipFilePath & "xl\workbook.xml" For Input As xmlFile
xmlFileContent = Input(LOF(xmlFile), xmlFile)
Close xmlFile

'Manipulate the text in the file to remove the workbook protection
xmlStartProtectionCode = 0
xmlStartProtectionCode = InStr(1, xmlFileContent, "<workbookProtection")
If xmlStartProtectionCode > 0 Then

    xmlEndProtectionCode = InStr(xmlStartProtectionCode, _
        xmlFileContent, "/>") + 2 ''"/>" is 2 characters long
    xmlProtectionString = Mid(xmlFileContent, xmlStartProtectionCode, _
        xmlEndProtectionCode - xmlStartProtectionCode)
    xmlFileContent = Replace(xmlFileContent, xmlProtectionString, "")

End If

'Manipulate the text in the file to remove the modify password
xmlStartProtectionCode = 0
xmlStartProtectionCode = InStr(1, xmlFileContent, "<fileSharing")
If xmlStartProtectionCode > 0 Then

     xmlEndProtectionCode = InStr(xmlStartProtectionCode, xmlFileContent, _
         "/>") + 2 ''"/>" is 2 characters long
    xmlProtectionString = Mid(xmlFileContent, xmlStartProtectionCode, _
         xmlEndProtectionCode - xmlStartProtectionCode)
    xmlFileContent = Replace(xmlFileContent, xmlProtectionString, "")

End If

'Output the text of the variable to the file
xmlFile = FreeFile
Open zipFilePath & "xl\workbook.xml" & xmlSheetFile For Output As xmlFile
Print #xmlFile, xmlFileContent
Close xmlFile

'Create empty Zip File
Open sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip" For Output As #1
Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
Close #1

'Move files into the zip file
oApp.Namespace(sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip").CopyHere _
oApp.Namespace(zipFilePath).items
'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
On Error Resume Next
Do Until oApp.Namespace(sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip").items.Count = _
    oApp.Namespace(zipFilePath).items.Count
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

'Delete the files & folders created during the sub
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
FSO.deletefolder sourceFilePath & tempFileName

'Rename the final file back to an xlsx file
Name sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip" As sourceFilePath & sourceFileName _
& "_" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & "." & sourceFileType

'Show message box
MsgBox "The workbook and worksheet protection passwords have been removed.", _
vbInformation + vbOKOnly, Title:="Password protection"

End Sub
```

Then i was able to right click on a sheet... select all sheets... go to format... unhide sheets... then select the one hidden sheet and unhide it.